# Detect if window.DeviceOrientationEvent is supported by browser

Tags: javascript

I need to detect if a browser supports `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` to determine whether I can run my script on this device or not. So far I've tried

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) { ... }
```

and

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent === true) { ... } else { // device not supported }
```

Tested on Firefox and Android phone and although both say this API is supported, the script only works on a mobile device, because it actually requires device position change.

Is there a better way to check it? I really don't want to go the route of mobile device list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way. When the browser supports the event, it's there even if the device running the browser would never send it. Tested in Chrome on PC Desktop now.

Am afraid the only thing you can do is to start listening for the events, and then if none ever comes, you can deduce that the device does not support them. Also on mobile phones rotation detection is often off, to save battery, so even a device list would not really work.

Maybe you can suggest an extension the the API. However I'm not sure if it's even possible to implement because indeed sometimes a phone can have the detection off even though it supports it. Am not sure if there is anything in e.g. Android which would allow the browser to ask that, maybe.